# Changing the value of a row based on another row from a different column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I have a data frame with column A and B. I need help writing a function that takes all the null values in A and replaces them based on the value in B. If the value in column B is 'Very Good' or 'Good', then it should put 'Home' in A. If the value in column B is 'Fair' or 'Bad', then it should put 'Foreign' in A. And lastly, if the value in column B is 'Very Bad' or 'Worst', then it should put 'Central' in A.

```
#Here's the data:
df <- structure(list(`A` = c("Home", NA, "Foreign", NA, "Central", NA), 
                 `B` = c("Good", "Very Good", "Bad", "Fair", "Very Bad", "Worst")),
            row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


#Here's how the data look

     A       B
1   Home    Good
2   NA  Very Good
3   Foreign Bad
4   NA  Fair
5   Central Very Bad
6   NA  Worst

#Here's the expected result
     A       B
1   Home    Good
2   Home    Very Good
3   Foreign Bad
4   Foreign Fair
5   Central Very Bad
6   Central Worst
```

Comment: ```library(dplyr);df %>% mutate(A = case_when(B %in% c("Good", "Very Good") ~ "Home",
                            B %in% c("Bad", "Fair") ~ "Foreign",
                            B %in% c("Very Bad", "Worst") ~ "Central",))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(tmp = case_when(B %in% c("Good", "Very Good") ~ "Home",
                              B %in% c("Bad", "Fair") ~ "Foreign",
                              B %in% c("Very Bad", "Worst") ~ "Central")) %>% 
       mutate(A = if_else(is.na(A),tmp,A)) %>% 
       select(-tmp)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   A       B        
#>   <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 Home    Good     
#> 2 Home    Very Good
#> 3 Foreign Bad      
#> 4 Foreign Fair     
#> 5 Central Very Bad 
#> 6 Central Worst
```

Comment: Question: what does the tmp do? what does the second mutate do?

Comment: @JusteNyirimana in your question you said *"a function that takes all the null values". In the first `mutate` I create a column based on the values of `B` (conditions you provided). Then, in the second one, I just replace the ones that are `NULL` (`NA`) with the values I created in the previous step and leave the other ones as is (in `if_else` the value for `False` is `A`). And at the end I get rid of `tmp` which was a helper column for updating values of `A`.

Comment: ps you can do it in one mutate, as in, you could replace `) %>% mutate(` with `, ` (and add the missing paren back at the end)

Comment: @IceCreamToucan is it more efficient? I personally don't like that since I think it adversely affects the readability.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought maybe you just weren't aware. No efficiency gains afaik.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Update: did a benchmark. On 5M rows, using one `mutate` is ~5 milliseconds faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(`A` = c("Home", NA, "Foreign", NA, "Central", NA), 
                     `B` = c("Good", "Very Good", "Bad", "Fair", "Very Bad", "Worst")),
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df %>% 
  mutate(AA = ifelse(B %in% c("Good", "Very Good"), "Home", ifelse(B %in% c("Bad", "Fair"), "Foreign", ifelse(B %in% c("Very Bad", "Worst"), "Central", NA))),
  A = ifelse(is.na(A), AA, A))         
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   A       B         AA     
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>  
#> 1 Home    Good      Home   
#> 2 Home    Very Good Home   
#> 3 Foreign Bad       Foreign
#> 4 Foreign Fair      Foreign
#> 5 Central Very Bad  Central
#> 6 Central Worst     Central
```